# Why do some hyperlinks to pages in wiki library work and some don't

Tags: hyperlink, wiki-pages

I am building SharePoint 2013 Wiki library with pages that will have training instructions for a new online SharePoint tool.  I wanted to create some imbedded links to all the wiki pages across the top of each page for easy navigation.  However, when I created the hyperlinks in OneNote and paste them back into the site four of the ten links don't work.  When I look at the link properties the address is blank.  If I add it manually and save the page the address is removed from the link tab.  This is true of all hyperlinks on the page to these four wiki pages.  I figure it has something to do with the four pages but I can't think of what.  I know it is not URL length because I have checked that and have other URL that work that are longer.

Comment: Some additional information, I have built link "ribbons" like this before using OneNote to create hyperlinks with names I want and pasting them onto a Wiki page.

Comment: So I found the potential problem.  Here is one of my working links: /ops/eda/ppriskmgt/RiskWiki/Step%201%20Create%20Screening.aspx.  Here is one of the broken ones: /ops/eda/ppriskmgt/RiskWiki/%E2%80%8BStep%203%20RAS%20Creation.aspx.  What is this "%E2%80%8B" in front of my page name?  All the broken links have it.

Comment: One more thing.  The links, even the ones that won't work in SharePoint, all work fine when I click on them in OneNote...  ...I am confused o_O

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be the extra character (`%E2%80%8BE`). This happens when you copy/paste urls from MS Word or other Office Apps. This is an invisible/non-printing formatting character (UTF-8: E2 80 8E with name *Left-to-right mark*).

So, you should decode your links when inserting those on SharePoint. Use an online URL Decoder/Encoder.

Comment: To find out more about encoded characters, check out w3school's HTML URL Encoding Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's encoding issue. Before copying it from source decode it properly by [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) tool. After decoding, you can see clean url.

Encoded URL: `/ops/eda/ppriskmgt/RiskWiki/Step%201%20Create%20Screening.as‌​px`
Decoded URL:  `/ops/eda/ppriskmgt/RiskWiki/Step 1 Create Screening.as‌​px`

**Resolution:** Update all corrupted links.